# gurobi.LinExpr: Extract the float value

Tags: python

How Could I extract the float value from an array like this? I want to plot it

```
array([[None],
       [<gurobi.LinExpr: 0.18>],
       [<gurobi.LinExpr: 0.18>],
       [<gurobi.LinExpr: 0.18>],
       [<gurobi.LinExpr: 1.069>]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2D array. You access it using:

```
a[i][j]
```

However, you will get a `gurobi.LinExpr` from which you need to extract the actual value.

Comment: Yes, that's right... I'm only need the value in order to plot it.. The main problem comes from varf = Touf.getVars()..  Any idea?